# Wkhtmltopdf/Snappy on CentOS 6

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I've installed wkhtmltopdf 0.11 and KNP\Snappy in order to try and generate PDFs from HTML within my Symfony2 project. I'm running CentOS 6 x64.

Wkhtmltopdf throws the following:

```
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
Segmentation fault
```

Unless there is an active X server and I specify --use-xserver when I try to generate on the command line.

This translates to the following PHP error:

```
RuntimeException: The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:\nstderr: \"wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server \n\"\nstdout: \"\"\ncommand: \/usr\/local\/bin\/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --use-xserver...
```

However, when I start the X server and then run wkhtmltopdf with PHP, I get the same error with or without --use-xserver, so I think PHP can't find the X server.

How can I get PHP to use the X server, so that wkhtmltopdf can generate PDFs from within PHP/Symfony2?

My code:

```
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
        return $snappy->getOutput($html, array(
            'use-xserver' => true
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems:
1) I should have used getOutputFromHtml() and not getOutput()
2) There is some bug in v0.11, which is documented here: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/180